# How good is Redis for serving as messaging platform between threads in a multi-threaded application?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, redis

I'm writing a multi-threaded application in Node which will have one parent process and 100-500 child processes. Parent needs to send a task to child and child needs to tell the parent it's done with the assigned task.

I plan to use Redis pub/sub for those messages between parent/child. Is this a good choice if there are gonna be 25k messages per minute?

Comment: yes, that should be perfectly doable. redis can easily handle that load.

Comment: Just a nitpick, if you are using child *processes*, it's not a multi*threaded* application.